# What is difference between module and library in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, c3.js

I am working on [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) and [c3js](http://c3js.org/) where both depends on [d3js](https://d3js.org/). Here for [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) we need to inject "nvd3" as dependency injection where as for [c3js](http://c3js.org/) we only give the file path and we wont inject anything.

Can anyone explain the difference in implementing [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) and [c3js](http://c3js.org/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems **you need both** *giving the file path* **and** *injecting a dependency*. and i think that you referring [`angular-nvd3`](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart) as `nvd3`

[`angular-nvd3`](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart) is an angular module that wraps the original [`nvd3`](http://nvd3.org/) charts library. It has [angular directives](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp) to help you use `nvd3` charts in your angular app (with bindings and more).

**For example ([view it online](http://plnkr.co/edit/bJY8sAVsin9x1XxOtcny?p=preview)):**

```
<nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
```

---

**The reason you have to use *"dependecy injection"*** in angular is because the way angular integrates with 3rd party modules: when you want to use third party **angular modules**, you are required to declare it as a dependency in your app module definition.

For instance, This syntax means that you declare an angular app called `myApp` and it has a dependency to [`angular-nvd3`](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart) :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3'])
    .controller(...)
    .service(...)
```

In addition to that, you need to include the 3rd party library code in your main html file, for example:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">  <!-- it's important for d3.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js"></script> <!-- or use another assembly -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.css">
```